# Why is apache accepting this invalid range request?

Tags: apache, http, curl

I'm trying to debug a ranged request issue in my app, so I've been using curl to see the headers. If I do `curl -v -H "Range: bytes=200-100" THEURL` the server responds with:

```
< HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
< Date: Sat, 19 Jan 2013 17:46:52 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Content-Range: bytes 200-100/1096985137
< Etag: --REDACTED BY OP--
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed
```

Wouldn't returning 206 imply that the content range is valid and that range is going to be served?

Another thing I've noticed is that even if I use a valid, but small, content range like `Range: bytes=0-100`, the server responds with `206` but sends way more data than 100 bytes.
Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: It seems no matter what range I send this server, I always get back the full download. Strange.

Comment: Can you provide 2 more pieces of info: 1. The version of Apache and 2. If you have the same result with non-compressed content (such as an image file)?  I have attempted to replicate issue and got full payload but with `200` instead of `206`, so invalid range probably is treated as negative number and thus as "no limit" but maybe the response itself differs between versions or content-types.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a military server and the only information I can get is from the server header the server returns. When I try to download a `.sig` file using the ranges: `Range: bytes=0-1` or `Range: bytes=1-0` I am always returned a 206 and the full size of the file.

Comment: Might be a reaction to http://httpd.apache.org/security/CVE-2011-3192.txt, one of the fixes until a patch came out was to mess with the Range header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go ahead and answer my own question, even though the answer is unsatisfying. Turns out it was just a bug with the version of Apache running on the server. Once the server was updated the problem was resolved.